# Merge Lists + update items

Tags: java

I have e.g. following `Lists`:

```
List<tst> listx; // tst object has properties: year, A, B, C, D 

year A B C D
------------
2013 5 0 0 0 // list1
2014 3 0 0 0

2013 0 8 0 0 // list2
2014 0 1 0 0

2013 0 0 2 0 // list3
2014 0 0 3 0

2013 0 0 0 1 // list4
2014 0 0 0 5
```

if I use `addAll` method, the `listTotal` will be:

```
year A B C D
------------
2013 5 0 0 0 // listTotal
2014 3 0 0 0
2013 0 8 0 0
2014 0 1 0 0
2013 0 0 2 0
2014 0 0 3 0
2013 0 0 0 1
2014 0 0 0 5
```

How to merge them to the `listRequired` which would be like this?

```
year A B C D
------------
2013 5 8 2 1 // listRequired
2014 3 1 3 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Map<Integer, Tst>` containing, for each year (the key of the map) the `Tst` you want for this year as a result.

Iterate through your `listTotal` and, for each Tst:

- if the year of the `Tst` isn't in the map yet, then store the `Tst` for this year
- else, get the Tst from the map and merge it with the current Tst

In the end, the `values()` of the map is what you want in your `listRequired`.

Code:

```
Map<Integer, Tst> resultPerYear = new HashMap<>();
for (Tst tst : listTotal) {
    Tst resultForYear = resultPerYear.get(tst.getYear());
    if (resultForYear == null) {
        resultPerYear.put(tst.getYear(), tst);
    }
    else {
        resultForYear.merge(tst);
    }
}
Set<Tst> result = resultPerYear.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

use a map to maintain a mapping from year to the TST structure.
iterate each item of the lists, retrieve the corresponding TST structure and update the A/B/C/D attributes manually

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by defining a custom merge method:

```
List<tst> merge (List<tst> listA, List<tst> listB)
```

which merges the properties of each element in listA with the element of the same index in listB.

Call this method iteratively on list1, ...list4 to get listRequired.